# I'm getting an import error with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I started learning selenium and at first my pip install didn't work but I got it working when I installed selenium. I ran the code and I dint get any errors, but when I changed my import to from selenium import WebDriver,
it gave me circular import error.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc&ab_channel=TechWithTim")
```

And this is my tech error it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\----\Desktop\New folder\selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "c:\Users\-----\Desktop\New folder\selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from partially initialized module 'selenium' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\----\Desktop\New folder\selenium.py)
```

I have updated pip. And I cheeked that I have selenium installed

Answer (score 2):

It's important to have a good understanding of how Python imports work.

When you attempt to import a module or package, Python follows a specific search path to find the appropriate file or library:

1. First, Python looks in the current working directory (cwd). If it finds an importable file or library there, it will import it from the cwd.
2. If nothing is found in the cwd, Python will search the site-packages directory.
3. If the import still fails, an error will be raised.

Now, consider the example where you have a file named 'selenium.py' that is importable. If you then try to import 'selenium' within the same file, Python will look for 'selenium.py' in the cwd, which in this case is the file itself. This creates a circular import, which can cause issues. as @kaliiiiiiiii mentioned.

To avoid this problem, it's important to never use package or library names as file names.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to call your file `selenium.py`.
This issue occurs, because it tries to import from itsself.